# Brute force base 256 multiplication

Tags: java, arrays, math

In my computer science class, I was given an algorithm to multiply two same-length binary numbers. I was instructed to convert it to multiply base 256 numbers and implement it in Java, but I can't seem to get the correct output and I don't know what I'm missing.

The algorithm that I was given:

```
MULTIPLY(U,V)
  define array W[1..2n] for k = 1 to 2n
  W[k] = 0 // Initialize result
  for j=1 to n
    c = 0 // Carry bit
    for i = 1 to n
      t = U[i]V[ j] + W [i+j] + c
      W[i+j] = t mod 2 // lower bit 
      c= /2 // upper bit
    k = i+j
    while k ≤ 2n and c ≠ 0 // propagate carry bit
      t=W[k]+ c
      W[k]=tmod2 // lower bit 
      c=/2 // upper bit 
      k++
  return W
```

My attempt:

```
private static Byte[] bruteMultiply(Byte[] U, Byte[] V) {
    Byte[] W = new Byte[U.length * 2];

    for (int k = 0; k < W.length; k++) {
        W[k] = 0;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < U.length; j++) {
        int c = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < U.length; i++) {
            int t = (U[i] & 0xFF) * (V[j] & 0xFF) + (W[i + j] & 0xFF) + c;
            W[i + j] = (byte) (t % 256);
            c = t / 256;
        }
        int k = U.length + j;
        while ((k < 2 * U.length) && (c != 0)) {
            int t = (W[k] & 0xFF) + c;
            W[k] = (byte) (t % 256);
            c = t / 256;
            k++;
        }
    }

    return W;
}
```

When I feed it the arrays `[197, 33, 151, 79]` and `[248, 164, 50, 235]`, I get `[216, 234, 132, 91, 206, 122, 31, 73]` when `[191, 118, 251, 78, 251, 255, 83, 133]` was expected.

I don't know what I'm missing or where I went wrong. Any suggestions or pointers would be helpful!

Comment: Debug your program!

Comment: `W[i+j] = t mod 2` => `W[i + j] = (byte) (t % 256)` ???

Comment: Debugging is a crucial skill to learn, and it's best to learning it as you learn how to program. If you advance in the complexity of programs you write without advancing in the complexity of programs you're able to debug, you'll be in for a world of trouble before long. Basic debugging skills are outside the scope of Stack Overflow -- maybe your teacher or teaching assistant can help?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose, That's where I think the bug might be, but I'm using `t mod 256` to  to get the remainder in 256 instead of base two, but I might not be understanding the multiplication correctly. I convert it to a byte to store it into the byte array.

Comment: @EJP I saw that in the while loop I made typo'd and put c = t / 2. I corrected it and ran the code again and will update the results and code. The top chunk is the pseudocode I was given, and the bottom is my code.

Comment: Maybe you start with much smaller arrays, I would suggest first one, then 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: try to multiply `[79, 151,33, 197]` and `[235, 50, 164, 248]` with your code instead and compare the result to the target result.

I believe it is time for you to learn about the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Generally your implementation looks OK but you use different endianness from the one in the example. Once you fix it, I think you'll get the correct answer.

P.S. I see no good reason to use [`Byte`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html) rather than `byte` in your array. This is another tricky difference that you probably should learn about.

Comment: So you think its that I'm storing the values in the wrong order? Also, I'm using `Byte` since I initially accept the values as an `ArrayList<Byte>` and then convert to `Byte[]`.

Comment: @LeviMuniz, 1) See my Hint that I've added 2) It is not that easy to say that the order is "wrong" because there is no universal rule that prescribes some order. If you look at the linked wiki article you may find that both are really used in practice. I'd prefer to say, that you use an order different from the one used in the example.

Comment: So humor me here; I reversed the inputs, and I didn't get the right answer. After staring at it for a few moments, I realized that I got the right answer in reverse order! Thank you for pointing out my oversight of how to properly store data :P

Comment: @LeviMuniz. I still think that you should read the wiki article (or some other substantial material) on **_big-endian vs little-endian_** because this is a quite important practical topic to understand and it is also very easy once you've got it.

Comment: I took a glance at it and it made me facepalm once I understood its implications. I'll read more in-depth later tonight.